# replacing <br> with a space with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have the following html

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            Cross<br>Section
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I tried the following

```
$('ul li a').text().replace('<br>', '&nbsp;');
```

but it doesnt work

Could someone assist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try selecting the `br` and then [replacing](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/) it with the space.

```
$('ul li a br').replaceWith('&nbsp;');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uXasp/

Comment: will display with `'&nbsp;'` visible as text. I tried that one firts

Comment: I retract that..I must have left out semicolon or something, was actually my first response also

Answer (score 3):

This should work

```
$('ul li a br').replaceWith(' ')
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/euTSs/

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
 $('ul li a').text($('ul li a').text().replace('<br>', '&nbsp;'));
```